# SQL Server 2005: Difference between SQL mail and DB mail

Tags: sql-server-2005, dbmail, sqlmail

Ok. I know SQL Mail is less secure and old, but what are the real advantages and differences between the two?

I read [this article,](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/05/sql-server-difference-between-database-mail-and-sqlmail/) which is pretty straight forward, but I was hoping to get someone to tell me why (if any) would you want to use SQL mail? Is it really out dated?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benefits of Database Mail over SQL Mail

1. Database Mail has the option of limiting file sizes to prevent sending large attachments
2. Database Mail can be configured with multiple SMTP accounts and with multiple profiles
3. No impact on the database performance, the mailing process is external
4. Having access to the mail history

**Database mail :**

Based on SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol).

Introduced in Sql 2005.

No need to install Outlook.

Depend on Service Broker service.

More secure than Sqlmail.

**SQLMail**

Based on MAPI (Messaging Application Programming Interface).

Used prior versions of Sql server 2005.

Require Outlook to be installed.

Leass secure than Database mail.

Link :
[Database Mail](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx)

[database-mail-vs-sql-mail](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/database-mail-vs-sql-mail/)